# Is it possible to customize or extend the functionality the Phone/contacts application on android phone

Tags: android

I want to customize the contacts or phone application on Android mobile. For instance adding more details while creating a contact. Adding an additional button to the screen that is displayed when a contact is selected. This button should trigger some custom functionality.

Comment: you have to create your own contacts application

Comment: Yes, you need to have root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A programmer can create a separate application for managing contacts that has the features that you seek.

> I want to customize the contacts or phone application on Android mobile.

There are ~1.5 billion Android devices in use, spanning thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of built-in "contacts or phone applications" on those devices. You cannot extend any of them, unless they happen to have some API to allow for that. I am not aware of any that do.